# Hibernate question

Tags: hibernate

I do not understand why Gavin King call **org.hibernate.Query** an interface.
As long as I know, **an interface is a group of related methods with empty bodies** and this
'interface' has methods already implemented.
I will appreciate any answer about it.

Answer (score 1):

`org.hibernate.Query`, like every interface in Java, has only method declarations, no method bodies. I don't know why you think it has implemented methods, it doesn't.